# AngularJs tooltip directive - Add style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, tooltip

I have defined a tooltip:

```
 window.myApp.directive 'atooltip', ->

   restrict: 'A'
   link: (scope, element, attrs) ->

     on_enter = ->
       $(element).tooltip('show')
     on_leave = ->
       $(element).tooltip('hide')

     $(element).hover(on_enter, on_leave)
```

Use it in my html file like this -->

```
<span toolipt atooltip data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="CLICK TO ADJUST PRICING">
          {{ something }}
        </span>
```

How can I change background-color, font etc., also I have more text to add in tooltip, how to format text, can I use html?

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation about jQuery or angular.element, those offer the funcionality you want.  `element.css ("background-color","white")`.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? ;)

Comment: Now it is an answer :D

Comment: element.css ("background-color","white")  where can I use this ??

Comment: Try adding it to on enter method and on leave after tool tip show line to change CSS.